# templateUrl does not work for me

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I use the seed structure as per angular.io get started project. Everything OK so far.

Now I wanted to change the top component to have a view from a separated file and I get into troubles. The working code is:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       template: '<h1>Angular2</h1>',
       directives: []
})
export class AppComponent {
       constructor() {  
       }
}
```

Then I change the template to templateUrl like so:

`templateUrl: 'app.component.html',`

where I have in this file the exact same code as before

`<h1>Angular2</h1>`

Seems to be obvious to work but it does not. It does not spit errors but it does not display anything except the 'loading....' message as in the get started demo

Thanks for helping

Peter

Comment: Are you sure you have the template in the correct directory?  If it is in the same directory as the component it should be
`templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',`

Comment: try putting templateUrl in @View decorator.

Comment: Thanks, the 'app/app.component.html' correction solves the problem. Reason is unclear. Is templateUrl referencing the project root?

Answer (score 23):

Add moduleId: module.id in the @Component decorator. If you don't have that then Angular 2 will be looking for your files at the root level.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

Check this [article](http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/)

Answer (score 4):

You have to write path from the build path.

```
templateUrl: 'build/app.component.html'
```

Answer (score 4):

Give the path from the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with your 'main' component, you may use (absolute path):

```
'./your_component_name.html'
```

in your case:

```
'./app.component.html',
```

If other component - you have couple of choices:

1. as said before - use moduleId
2. use `/app/your_component_html_filename` like example `/app/dashboard.html` or `./app/dashboard.html`
3. use full path - not a good idea, but you may

About using of .css NOT from your 'main' component:

2. use `app/your_component_css_filename` like example `app/dashboard.css` without first slash '/'!!!

Comment: by the way at project that i created using CLI ALL the template/style paths work Only with path like './your_component_name.html'

Answer (score 1):

use full path like app/app.component.html
or use absolute path like ./app.component.html 
./ for same directory

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems absolute path. The compnent is requiring absolute path to be mentioned. This is my file structure,

[image]

The following is not working,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: 'product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['product-list.component.css']
})
```

As of my knowledge, The HTML template Url or the Url for the style-sheet needs to be given in absolute path. I tried the following and working.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    //template: `<h3>PRODUCT LISTINGS </h3>`
    templateUrl:'app/products/product-list.component.html'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i resolved this issue by adding moduleid property of component

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    // templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
    templateUrl:'app.component.html'
})
```

and it works as expected. 
And i get some idea from this url : 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAPQF_GA7Qg&feature=youtu.be