# Angular 2 failed to load navbar.html

Tags: angular, mean-stack

[image]

Here is code of my components while using template:'' code is working fine but while using templateUrl it is giving error

App.component

```
import { navbarComponent } from './HomeValley/navbar';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1>
            <navbar></navbar>`
})
export class AppComponent { }

Navbar .ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'navbar',
    templateUrl:'app/../navbar.html'
})

export class navbarComponent{}

app.module.ts
import { navbarComponent } from './HomeValley/navbar';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,navbarComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you create this on plunkr ?

Comment: No i didn't use plunker

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is fine but filename is not according to convention.
File names should be like-

Navbar.**component**.ts if navbarComponent is your **component**

likewise follow the convention for html and css file (i.e Navbar.component.html and Navbar.component.css )

Here is working example of your code
https://plnkr.co/edit/0NVEL2UW35Qpwgjz4izT?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'navbar',
    template:'<h1>Hi</h1>'
})

export class navbarComponent{}
```

For more detail follow : https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Edit1: another problem i found out that, use absolute path.

Check out this question for more update: [templateUrl does not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844206/templateurl-does-not-work-for-me)

Comment: can you provide me the link for angular 2 final full version template with everything updated?

Comment: @AliMirza let me know if you have any question

Comment: @AliMirza did u tried my solution, its working for me.

Comment: have u checked my template?

Comment: yes i checked your template may be there is a problem with my project now i created new project and its working fine

Comment: I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the url of the navbar.html

**navbar.ts** should be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'navbar',
    templateUrl:'./navbar.html'
})
```

That means that you have your `navbar.html` next to your `navbar.ts`.

**UPDATE**

Also you can try with the full path:

**navbar.ts** should be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'navbar',
    templateUrl:'./HomeValley/navbar.html'
})
```

Here's a plunker that I made with a working example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/NMJpI7DQ9hhImGGZTQ3L?p=preview

Comment: Your `navbar.ts` is in the same folder that your `navbar.html`?

Comment: Yes both files are in same folder

Comment: Your error says that your are using an absolute url like this one: `templateUrl:'navbar.html'`or `templateUrl:'/navbar.html'`, just put that DOT before the slash.

Answer (score 0):

### Navbar .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'app-navbar',               <-----------try this
   templateUrl: './navbar.html'
})
```

and pass selector as

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

### or, try to import as:-

```
import { navbarComponent } from './HomeValley/navbar/navbar';
```

### or, As below:-

```
 Get an IDE- Visual Studio Code

    1) Install node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/

   Open command Prompt  and run commands 
  -----------------------------------------------
    2) check `node -v` and `npm -v` in command prompt
    3) Install angular cli as `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` in command prompt
    4) check ng -v 
    5) Generate, New project(Refer documenttation below) by typing- ng new Myapp  
    5) then, npm install 
    6) ng serve --o 

    Refer, this link:- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli  for commands.
```

Comment: Just try this, It may help you.

Comment: Actually I am new on stack overflow can u tell me how to show you structure

Comment: Is your navbarComponent  is inside-  HomeValley folder>navbar folder

Comment: yes it is inside in Home valley folder as well as navbar.html is also inside home valley folder

Comment: Updated answer, try this.

Comment: No Sir didn't work out may be there is a problem in my angular project files?

Comment: If your project structure is like app folder(containing all css, html,.ts files files)>any component folder