# TemplateUrl in Angular 6 w/TS 3.0.3 Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript

My dev environment:

- Mac OS 10.13.6
- Angular 6
- TypeScript 3.0.3
- Node 8.11.4
- NPM 6.4.1
- Not using Angular CLI or WebPack

The following code is a basic Angular ***app.component.ts*** file, and it works fine:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: '<h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Hello Darkness My Old Friend';

    constructor() {
     //some method
    }    
}
```

However, it will not work when I replace line 5 with this: `templateUrl: './app.component.html'` It refuses to load an external template and the browser window is blank. I decided not to post the **app.component.ts** code because I'm 100% certain it's correct. It's imported correctly and listed under `@ngModule`. Also, I'm getting this error in the console but I cannot find much on it. Looks like something do to with zone.js? However, it might not have anything to do with the issue:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load app.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load app.component.html undefined zone.js:665:17
api.onUnhandledError
http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:665:17
handleUnhandledRejection
http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:692:9
_loop_1

//a few more errors, yada yada yada
```

If anyone has a quick technical fix I could try, I'd appreciate it. However, right now I'm thinking I might have to fix this structurally. I might have to rollback to Angular 5 and TS 2.7. If anyone else is not using the CLI or WebPack and you have no problems with `templateUrl`, please post a bullet list of your setup so I can duplicate that myself and hopefully get past this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Angular v6 supports TS v3. How did you update?

Comment: UH, is "I don't know" acceptable? LOL. This is good info though and I'll keep in mind this could be it.

Comment: If in doubt you are probably best off doing a clean install on it by generating a new project with latest CLI and pasting everything except the configs into the new project. Seriously, otherwise it hurts.

Comment: I have felt it first hand. Trust me. Throw out the configs and your package.json or you will be haunted by typerrors and cryptic messages

Comment: can you show us your project structure? may be path to app.component.html is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/q/34844206/2742156

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to upgrade using `@angular-cli` and with [this guide](https://update.angular.io/).

You should really be using the cli since it knows how to update your `package.json` and even more important, your configs!

You might need some configs updated and also you should Angular decide which TS version to use, AFAIK TS 3 and up are not supported yet. Try `2.9.2` instead. 
But I do recommend getting a clean project setup. Integrating task runners can be pescy but if you use the angular cli and its options well you should not need grunt.

Comment: I began using the CLI, but it had too many of it's own opinions on how things should be done. I'm trying to integrate my Grunt front-end environment into Augular's and I've solved every other issue but this one. I'll try downgrading to an earlier version of TS.

Comment: try v 2.9.2, we are using it with angular 6

Comment: what exactly do you need the task runner for? maybe we can integrate that stuff into angular configs, where it belongs. angular already has a task runner

Comment: We need it because it's what we use and we've gotten very good with it. We like the granular control instead of having to wrestle with other things trying to do stuff a different way. We have everything set up just the way we need and do not want to go through the time consuming and costly process of setting up another environment. We do not need Angular to "takeover" things for us. Rather, we want it to compliment and enhance what we already have. After the TS renders, we'll do the CSS and JS post processing. We're not looking for an "all in one box" approach.

Comment: We have incorperated all of our build and dev processes for testing, deployment, scss and so on with the cli. it hot-reloads, builds and tests. Just consider it.
Maybe read into it a little.